# WebDesign: Header file, but with custom Page titles?

Tags: php, html, header, title

I've been using headers to create templates for websites.
It's easy, and very convenient for debugging.

I now face the problem of using head BUT with custom page titles.
If this is my **header.php** >

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Site : ??? </html>
    </head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

I need ??? to be replaced for every page.

Is this possible? If so, how? Thank you. : )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not knowing more about your file inclusion scheme, the simplest way would be:

page2.php

```
<?php
$pageTitle = 'Page 2';
include 'header.php';
?>

<div>My content</div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

header.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Site : <?php echo $pageTitle ?> </title>
    </head>
<body>
```

footer.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

webbiedave's answer is perfectly fine, but in the long run, you should really learn to use either a decent template language (Smarty, [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/)), or a PHP framework that has it's own templating. Kohana and Codeigniter are both pretty easy to get into.

Comment: Agreed. As his experience and needs progress, he should make the leap. My answer was just a simple starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If i were to add some code before including the header, will it help?

```
<?php
    $currentPage = "Random Page Title";
    include "header.php";
?>
```

And then use the value in header.php so print the page title?

Comment: yes but if you define current page as "random page title" it will be "random page title" on everypage or you will have to edit every page where you want a title... in the long run this is bad. Using a database will help by allowing you to select the page title.

Answer (score 0):

you could query a DB for the title of a page and then print it using php :)

Edit:

Looking back at the problem , depending on how you have your website designed this may not be the simplest solution. But if you are already using some sort of ID system this should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will help definitely. But you need to do a little customization.

First of all, make sure that you connect to the database, if you want to query / fetch data from database. For this to happen, include the "config.php" page at the very beginning of the script, in which your database connection logic will be present.

Then, write your query to fetch data from that database, and assign that value to the required variable for using it in the header page.

Lastly, include your "header.php" page.

For "config.php" page:-

Logic of Database Connection, like using of "mysql_connect()" & "mysql_select_db()" functions.

For "custom.php" page:-

```
<?php
  include "config.php";

  $sql = "SELECT pageTitle FROM db_table WHERE condition = 'something'";
  $sql_exe = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Fetching Page Title");
  if( mysql_num_rows($sql_exe) ) {
    $currentPage = mysql_result($sql_exe, 0, 0);
  }
  else {
    $currentPage = "Random Page Title";
  }
  mysql_free_result($sql_exe);

  include "header.php";
?>
```

Also, if you want, you can always use some class for mysql connection & queries, to fetch data. But this is how it always work.

Answer (score 0):

you can call javascript to change the title of the page dynamically, this is a better solution if you have a master file index.php that calls all other includes

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this:

if you married up your php filenames with your page titles

you could use explode or str replace to make it more user friendly to replace commas or underscores for example.

```
   <?php
    echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    ?>
```

or

```
  <?php
    // my_page_title.php
   $var=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $pagetitle=str_replace("_"," ",$var);

    // my page title
    ?>       
    <title> My Site : <?php echo $pagetitle; ?> </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected 1 small error in Webbiedave's header.php entry

```
</html> should be </title>
```

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Site : <?php echo $pageTitle ?> </title>
    </head>
<body>
```